# Argument of type '{ title: string; description: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: {}; title: {}; description: {}; }'

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I was trying created model with Sequelize. But method createPost() throw Error:

```
Argument of type '{ title: string; description: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: {}; title: {}; description: {}; }'. 
Property 'id' is missing in type '{ title: string; description: string; }' but required in type '{ id: {}; title: {}; description: {}; }'.
```

I'm not sure why created() method want as argument type { id: {}; title: {}; description: {}; } and how can I solve it. Without typescript it's ok.

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../util/database';

const postTable = sequelize.define('post', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: Sequelize.STRING
});

class Post {
    title: string;
    description?: string;

    constructor(title: string, description: string) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    static findAll() {
        return postTable.findAll();
    }

    createPost(){
        postTable.create({
            title: this.title,
            description: this.description
        });
    }
}
export default Post;
```

Comment: Remove this: `allowNull: false` for id

Comment: I tried it but I have same issue again.

Comment: Check my update in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sequelize will assume your table has a id primary key property by default

You can optionally just remove the `id` and sequelize will handle it by default.

Or you could...

No need for the id attribute of the object to have `allowNull: false`. That is something handled automatically by sequelize.

Having `allowNull: false` will make sequelize check if `id` attribute exists when you're creating an object and logically it won't exist as that is something that will be added later.

Change this:

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
}
```

to this:

```
id: {
     type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
     autoIncrement: true,
     primaryKey: true
}
```